# How to clear previous values from browser console

Tags: javascript, web, console.log

For example if I type

```
var x = 5;
x;
```

console output is 5 (as expected)

But when I want to start afresh and clear the console(using ctrl+L or clear(); ),the console clears up but x still contains value 5 (as can be checked by typing `x` in console)

I don't want console to remember any previous data after using clear.How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`clear()` does just that - *clears* the console.

But to add something new - you can't delete your variables, at least not when they're declared this way. The only 100% sure way of doing this, is simply refreshing the page.

To elaborate: you can delete only object's properties, so if you do this:

```
x = 5;
delete x; // returns true
```

It will work, but if you assign your value using `var` keyword:

```
var x = 5;
delete x; // returns false
```

...then you can't delete it.

To better understand what you can and what you can't delete and *why* - you can read more under this link: http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/.